# fit() by Keras doesnt accept my numpy array of numpy arrays data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

hey I have just started learning deep learning and I'm trying to train my model with fit() function
but I'm having a problem with passing my training data to fit(), I'll show you my process so you could get a good understanding of how my data looks.

that's how i took data from Keras:

```
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = data.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

which is a numpy array of lists

I also tried to make every list inside the array consistent by making all the lists as a numpy array with the length of 250.
actually there's a function named keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences() that does exactly what I try to do and also, fit() works with that function but I wanted to create my own function, here is my function:

```
 def make_data_const_250(data):

    for i in range(len(data)):

        data[i]=np.asarray(data[i])#converting list to numpy
        if len(data[i]) < 250:
            for j in range(250-len(data[i])):
                data[i]=np.append(data[i],word_index["<SPACE>"])

        elif len(data[i]) > 250:
            data[i] = data[i][ :250]
    return data
```

then I tried to make the data consistent:

```
train_data=make_data_const_250(train_data)
test_data=make_data_const_250(test_data)
```

which is like doing:

```
train_data=keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, value=word_index["<SPACE>"],padding="post",maxlen=250)
```

and doing the same thing with test_data

I printed the data type after calling my function and Kera's function and both of them give a numpy array of numpy arrays.

then I called fit() function:

```
x_val=train_data[:10000] # validation data
x_train=train_data[10000:] # training data

y_val=train_labels[:10000] #validation labels

y_train=train_labels[10000:]#training lables

fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=7, batch_size=512,validation_data=(x_val,y_val),verbose=1)
```

the error that it gives is:
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

and with Kera's function it worked and with my function it didn't , I would like to know why fit() function won't' accept my numpy array of numpy arrays and how do i fix the error, also I'm pretty new to numpy arrays as well so maybe the problem is related to that, thank you for your help!

Comment: In your numpy array the shape should be consistent. Also, post the model summary.

Comment: Check the shapes of your arrays, as well as the dtype of your inner arrays and post again.